# CMake SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES

Tags: compiler-errors, cmake

```
SET(LIBHELLO_SRC hello.c)
ADD_LIBRARY(hello_static STATIC ${LIBHELLO_SRC})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(hello_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "hello")
GET_TARGET_PROPERTY(OUTPUT_VALUE hello_static OUTPUT_NAME)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(hello_static PROPERTIES CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT 1)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${OUTPUT_VALUE} PROPERTIES CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT 1)
MESSAGE(STATUS “This  is  the  hello_static  OUTPUT_NAME: ”${OUTPUT_VALUE})
```

when i run "cmake .." command,  gives a error about "CMake Error at lib/CMakeLists.txt:10 (SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES):
  SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES Can not find target to add properties to: hello
"
what should i do ,thanks a lot!

Comment: This is because `${OUTPUT_VALUE}` contains the string hello, not the target `hello_static`. Remove the line `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${OUTPUT_VALUE} PROPERTIES CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT 1)` and it should run.

Comment: oh ,thanks ,i get it@vre